# volume of region in a probability simplex with shannon entropy > c?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Let $S_n = \{(p_1, \cdots, p_n)| p_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1\}$. I.e. $S_n$ is a $n-1$-simplex.  Let
$$
E(p_1, \cdots, p_n) = -\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\ln p_i
$$
be the Shannon entropy.

I am stuck with the question, what is the $n-1$-Volume of $\{(p_1, \cdots, p_n)\in S_n \mid E(p_1, \cdots, p_n)>a\}$?

I mean I am interest in integral
$$
\int_{X}dV
$$
where $X= \{(p_1, \cdots, p_{n-1}) \mid p_i\geq 0, p_n = 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p_i\geq 0, E(p_1, \cdots, p_n)>a\}\subset {\mathbb R}^{n-1}$

Any non-trivial bounds are also interesting.

Comment: Do you already have the approximation for $a \approx \log n$?

Comment: No. that would be interesting. Is there any concentration phenomenon around $\ln n$?

Comment: See [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791203/what-do-the-level-sets-of-the-shannon-entropy-look-like?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Just some values from numerical simulation.
The horizontal axis is the entropy (in nats), and the vertical axis is the normalized volume.

[image]

The entropy tends to get concentrated around the mean, which is given by

$$ e(n)=\psi_0(n+1) + \gamma -1 \approx \log n -0.423 +\frac{1}{2n} $$

where $\psi_0$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought so.